# R code to import multiple xlsx files into one dataset

Tags: r, import, xlsx

I am trying to import datasets for each year from 2015-2019, their file names are the same aside from the year at the end (which I did not include in the code but rather used [0-9]). I was successful when using a similar code with the datasets that are csv files but when I try it with an xlsx file the dataset is showing up as null (empty).

**Successful csv code**

```
   dataname <- list.files(path = "path location", pattern = "filename_sameforalldatasets_[0-9]+.csv", full.names = T)
    dataname <- map(dataname, read_csv)
    dataname <- do.call(rbind, dataname)
```

**xlsx code showing up null**

```
dataname <- list.files(path = "Path location", pattern = "^[0-9]+ filename_sameforalldatasets_.xlsx", full.names = T)
   dataname <- map(dataname, read_xlsx)
   dataname <- do.call(rbind, dataname)
```

Comment: Did you success reading single files with read_xlsx(file)?

Comment: Yes, I can read in each file individually using read_xlsx

Comment: Have you verified that `list.files(path = "Path location", pattern = "^[0-9]+ filename_sameforalldatasets_.xlsx", full.names = T)` is returning the correct list of files?

Comment: `list.files(path = "Path location", pattern = "^[0-9]+ filename_sameforalldatasets_.xlsx", full.names = T)` is not returning any files. When I run that line it is showing up in my environment as empty

Comment: the issue lies probably with the regex in your pattern

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a different way to write my pattern?